Working on details on the Secretary Problem
I've been trying to follow this proof of the optimal way to solve the secretary problem (ref. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem). Everything is clear to me except where they are transforming the Riemann sum into a definite integral.
They claim that $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{r-1}{n}}\sum_{i=r}^{n}\frac{1}{\frac{i-1}{n}}\frac{1}{n}=x\int_{x}^{1}\frac{1}{t}dt$, where $x = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{r-1}{n}$ and $t = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{i-1}{n}$.
I get that the limit of a product is the product of the limits, so $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{r-1}{n}}\sum_{i=r}^{n}\frac{1}{\frac{i-1}{n}}\frac{1}{n}= x\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=r}^{n}\frac{1}{\frac{i-1}{n}}\frac{1}{n}$. But I am confused at exactly how we get to the integral.
I know that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = \lim_{n \to \infty}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{f(x_i)\Delta x_i}}$, where $\Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n}$. This does not seem obvious.

Let $m=n(1-x)$, so $m\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Then let $\Delta y=\frac{1-x}{m}=\frac 1n$, so $y_j=x+\frac{1-x}{m}j=\frac{nx+j}{n}$.
$$\int_x^1\frac 1t\mathrm dt=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^mf(y_j)\Delta y=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=0}^m\frac{1}
{nx+j}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=r}^n\frac{1}{i}$$
We ignored some individual terms to make things nicer. This is an approximation. More simply, it is well known that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\big(\big(\sum_{i=1}^k\frac 1i\big)-\ln k\big)=\gamma$, where $\gamma\approx 0.577$ is a constant. Therefore since $r\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, we see that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=r-1}^n\frac 1i=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1i-\sum_{i=1}^{r-2}\frac 1i=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln n+\gamma-\ln r-\gamma=\ln 1/x$$
you can fill the details from there.
